# Python's .pop() in dict vs list

Tags: python

Does anyone know why `.pop()` for dictionaries can have a default argument but for list it cannot? Is there some historical reasoning behind it or does it have something to do with `pop()` default behavior on list? (Removing the last element when no arguments are provided). Or is it just simply implementation thing that can't be done any other way?

Comment: Perhaps because it's analogous to dict.get which also accepts a default value, where `get` leaves the item in the dict (if it exists) while `pop` removes it (if it exists). Personally speaking, I think the use of the name `pop` here was not a good choice. That's an operation on a stack, not on an array (list) or associative array (dict), where it should be called remove or delete or similar.

Comment: Dictionaries at one point were unordered, so no way of being sure which one you want rid of, although I note the behaviour does extend to (the more recent) OrderedDict as well...

Comment: @Amiga500 they're referring to setting a default return value in `dict.pop` not the default parameter value

Comment: @Amiga500 *so no way of being sure which one you want rid of* `pop()` has a key parameter, it's pretty clear what value is being removed.

Comment: @Guy - yeah - that's my point - if you don't supply the key parameter - the default argument - then it won't know which one to pop. But if its actually alluding to the return, then I'm talking nonsense as usual :D

Comment: @Amiga500 If you don't provide a key you will get an error `pop expected at least 1 argument, got 0`.

Comment: @Guy they got tripped up and confused `dict.pop`'s `default` parameter with `list.pop`'s default behavior

Answer (score 0):

`dict.pop(v)` works like `list.remove(v)` and `dict.popitem()` is similar to `list.pop()` and you can do `del data[x]` on bought but the `__getitem__` in the `dict` evaluates an object instead a index and you can't access the items by the index but you can use the `dict.keys()` to translate an index to a value so you can override this functionality to work as a list with something like this:

```
class EDict(dict):

    def pop(self, index=-1):
        return dict.pop(self, tuple(self.keys())[index])

data = EDict({
    '1': 'a', '2': 'b',
    '3': 'c', '4': 'd',
})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(data)
    data.pop()
    print(data)
    data.pop(1)
    print(data)
```

(Amiga500 was probably referring to [this post](https://morepypy.blogspot.com/2015/01/faster-more-memory-efficient-and-more.html))

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definitive answer, but I have two thoughts on the subject.

1. Three methods of Python dictionaries have optional *default* parameter: `dict.get()`, `dict.setdefault()` and, yes, `dict.pop()`.  All of them essentially return *value*, associated with the *key*, so adding *default* to all of those is a consistent thing to do.

   Note that `dict.popitem()` doesn't accept the *key*, and consistently doesn't need *defult*.
2. Another thing is basic convenience.  Lists are sequences, and it's hard to imagine a case where you would need a default for `list.pop()`.  If you try to pop an item from outside of list "bounds", you've got a bug, and papering over possible failure with `list.pop(index, None)` wouldn't do much good.  On the other hand, it's quite common for dictionary to not contain a value for a specific key, so looking it up might very well be a normal situation.